# Auth0: Login on Website - Allow access to API in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, auth0

Using Auth0 for auth in 2 different ASP.NET Core-applications, how do I allow a user to register/login in one application (the website) and then use credentials somehow to call another application (the API)?

Is it possible to generate a bearer-token, **which doesn't expire** (but can be regenerated), which can be exposed on the website-app and then used in the HTTP-headers to access the API-app?

What other strategies could be used to make sure a user can use an API, without getting a graphical login-screen?

Answer (score 1):

The default JWT token lifetime is 30 days (2592000 seconds) , you can set the lifetime in dashboard . You can use [refresh token](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token/current) to renew the access token , Refresh tokens can also expire but are rather long-lived.

You can use [Resource owner flow](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant) / [client credential flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/client-credentials) to acquire access token for protected resource . But `Resource owner flow` needs user's credential, it's not safe to collect user's credential in a web application . And `client credential flow` uses client's credential which is also not meet your requirement since you need user's login . I am afraid currently there is no never expire JWT tokens in your scenario .